# Android setselected call on a view trigger child views too

Tags: android

As the title suggest, whenever i call setselected on a view, it will also trigger setselected on all it's child views. How to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

See how it's implemented (from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java)):

```
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    //noinspection DoubleNegation
    if (((mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_SELECTED) != 0) != selected) {
        mPrivateFlags = (mPrivateFlags & ~PFLAG_SELECTED) | (selected ? PFLAG_SELECTED : 0);
        if (!selected) resetPressedState();
        invalidate(true);
        refreshDrawableState();
        dispatchSetSelected(selected);
        notifyViewAccessibilityStateChangedIfNeeded(
                AccessibilityEvent.CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_UNDEFINED);
    }
}
/**
 * Dispatch setSelected to all of this View's children.
 *
 * @see #setSelected(boolean)
 *
 * @param selected The new selected state
 */
protected void dispatchSetSelected(boolean selected) {
}
```

There's nothing in place that would stop the call from happening on top level and it's up to the concrete implementation how to process / propagate that information...

Comment: It looks like dispatchSetSelected implemented on ViewGroup level. What i did was override it in custom view and it works now. Thanks for the pointer.